# Best technique for saving download list

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel, download-manager

im trying to develop a download manager for my college project using java. I wanna know the best technique that can be used to save the download list. Im using jtable and abstracttablemodel to display the download thread details. I want the download manager to remember the downloads after the application restarts.

Comment: how about a comma separated temporary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a file as @VD' said, but you might want to use something called [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).  It really depends on your needs.  Do you need to query this data, or do you just want to save and retrieve it?  If the latter, use Preferences.  If the former, use a database.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yea, i want it to just save and retrieve but also want it to frequently save the download progress and i dont want this process to be a big overhead for the app.

Comment: I'm sure Preferences will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could either save the data to a file (in JSON or something sensible), or use a simple database (sqlite is good for this kind of thing). Then load the data upon start up.

I'd probably go with an sqlite DB.